# In FastAPI can I make a input optional?

Tags: python, fastapi

To make my code manageable I am using classes to define the inputs into my endpoints. Here is an example:

```
class BaseRequest(BaseModel):
    name: str

class details(BaseRequest):
    age: int
    gender: str

@router.put('/people')
async def add_people(body: details):
    try:
        name, age, gender = body.name.upper(), body.age, body.gender

        # insert the person
        res = await main_db_instance.fetch_rows(f"INSERT INTO myDB.people (name, age, gender)"
                                                f" VALUES ('{name}', '{age}', '{gender}')"
                                                f" RETURNING *")
        return JSONResponse(jsonable_encoder(res), status_code=200)

    except Exception as exp:
        logger.exception(f'Exception while inserting the person: {exp}')
        return JSONResponse(status_code=500, content="Error inserting the person")
```

I would send this data:
{"name": "Bob" , "age": 25 , "gender": "Male" }
This works right now but everything is mandatory. Here are my questions:

1. What if gender is optional? or do I want to add a new data point to test without breaking all existing apps making API calls?
2. If something is optional, what do I do with the DB inserts? Would I need to create a variation of all possible combinations? Or can I insert null values so I just have one insert statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the types for those fields `Optional[...]` and give them default values:

```
class BaseRequest(BaseModel):
    name: str

class details(BaseRequest):
    age: int
    gender: Optional[str] = None
```

If the `gender` field is nullable in the database, you can then just do

```
res = await main_db_instance.fetch_rows(
    "INSERT INTO myDB.people (name, age, gender) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s) RETURNING *",
    (name, age, gender),
)
return JSONResponse(jsonable_encoder(res), status_code=200)
```

(see use of parametrization to avoid the SQL injection attacks your code is currently vulnerable to – not sure if your `main_db_instance` supports that, but it really **should**)

Comment: Beat me to this. I don't think `= None` is required like it is for dataclasses.

Comment: Thank you it worked(I added a comment of it not working but it was a user error..apparently sending commented out JSON messages isn't a possibility yet)

Comment: @BradyDean Having the default makes it possible to elide the value altogether.